# Can we create a WiFi access point wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge, bridging

I've googled and found out that to create a WiFi access point, I need to use a LAN cable to connect between the main router with Internet with the second router which acts as access point. But can I do it without a cable?

Here's my network diagram -> https://i.postimg.cc/jjgdMMTq/my-network-diagram.png

I want to use my Wifi router Archer C7 (AC1750) as a bridge or access point (doesn't matter which) to my main router (IP: 192.168.225.1) (a pocket WiFi device) which has Internet connection (via a SIM card).

Comment: Please be more clear on exactly how you envisage this working and what exactly you are trying to achieve. You should also list your hardware. The answer is a lot more nuanced and open to interpretation then you may realise.  (Technologies include AP clients, mesh network, repeaters and possibly other things like power line).

Comment: @davidgo it's odd that i was super clear in this question - https://superuser.com/questions/1591786/issue-with-wifi-bridging-via-wds-worked-once-but-fail-now and no one actually replied.